# Delay on Journey Entry when using a Salesforce Data Event Entry

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a Journey using the Salesforce Data Event. The data event is listening for a Contact Created or Updated with a field Lead Source set to 'Other'. The Entry takes a long time to happen. I created a Contact in Salesforce at 2:50PM PST. The Contact didn't enter the Journey until 3:43PM PST.

What would cause a delay in entry? Especially almost an hour. My understanding is once the Create or Update happens the Flow is supposed to be triggered.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I have started experiencing this since 2 weeks. All of a sudden the entry into the journey started taking too long. Not sure if Salesforce messes up something under the hood..

Comment: I'm experiencing similar issues.  Please update us if you discover anything.